# Sharekit Facebook not opening

Tags: facebook, sharekit

i am using sharekit in my ios App. Twitter and email are working fine but facebook is not. When i open facebook it pops out a dialog having blue boundary but nothing is written in it. There is a close button on left side but the dialog is empty. Whats the problem? Please help me. Also i have double checked Facebook APPid and Secret key in SHKconfig.h.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people are having the same problem.  ShareKit itself is an amateur attempt at a framework component and is so bug-ridden its pretty much worthless.  The problem your seeing relates to the Facebook Connect framework used by ShareKit.  Apparently Facebook has stopped all support for the Connect framework.  In other words, you are SOL.